# Can someone explain this GPU Vendor ID string?

Tags: gpu

> PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_13C2&SUBSYS_29743842&REV_A1\4&37E5E774&0&0020

I would like to find out the serial number of my GPU.

Is it part of the above Vendor ID string?

Comment: It purely depends on if the manufacture has implemented the Serial in this way. Quite often in my experience they haven't and it will be on the Graphics Card itself on a little sticker...

Answer (score 1):

According to [nVidia PCI Vendor and Devices for Geforce desktop](https://www.nvidia-drivers.eu/geforce-devices.html) webpage, `PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_13C2` is the Device ID of the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970 graphics card.

### <sub>How to show other information about your GPU</sub>

GPU-Z is a lightweight system utility designed to provide vital information about your video card and graphics processor. GPU-Z displays information about your adapter, GPU, and display including overclock, default clocks, 3D clocks, and more. It supports NVIDIA, ATI and Intel graphics devices.

You can run GPU-Z as a portable app from a USB flash drive without installing it on your computer's hard drive by downloading the [GPU-Z portable app](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/gpu-z-portable) for Windows.